# java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException when deleting lastSuccessful/lastStable jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

when running a jenkins job, the console reports this error:

```
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\jenkins\jobs\My Job\lastSuccessful
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.createSymlinkJava7(Util.java:1194)
    at hudson.Util.createSymlink(Util.java:1112)
    at hudson.model.Run.createSymlink(Run.java:1846)
    at hudson.model.Run.updateSymlinks(Run.java:1827)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
ln builds\lastStableBuild C:\jenkins\jobs\My Job\lastStable failed
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\jenkins\jobs\My Job\lastStable
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Util.createSymlinkJava7(Util.java:1194)
    at hudson.Util.createSymlink(Util.java:1112)
    at hudson.model.Run.createSymlink(Run.java:1846)
    at hudson.model.Run.updateSymlinks(Run.java:1828)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

Is this a bug or something i need to fix?

Comment: Does it happen as well when the job name does not contain blanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is in the bugtracker of Jenkins : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21330

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix this by releasing some locks that some program had on the folders.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the issue appears when moving Jenkins from one server to other. Seems that when copying the home folder, this issue appears.

In this [link](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215281777-After-creating-a-copy-of-the-local-Jenkins-home-lastSuccessful-fails-with-java-nio-file-DirectoryNotEmptyException) explains how to fix these erroneous directories. I copy the steps here for future reference:

```
# Logon on the master where you have the issue
ssh jenkins-machine
# Shutdown the jenkins master (take care that nothing is running)
sudo service jenkins stop
# Find all erroneous directories
find /opt/jenkins/jobs -type d \( -name "last*Build" -o -name "lastStable" -o -name "lastSuccessful" \)
# Review the list of erroneous directories
# Rename them
find /opt/jenkins/jobs -type d \( -name "last*Build" -o -name "lastStable" -o -name "lastSuccessful" \) -exec mv {} {}.err \;
# Restart jenkins
sudo service jenkins start
```

And if it works, remove the moved directories:

```
#In the future you can delete these directory if everything is fine with
find /opt/jenkins/jobs -type d -name "*.err" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Note that the script assumes that jenkins home is in `/opt/jenkins`. Change it to `/var/lib/jenkins` or your current jenkins path.