# java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\Jadayu\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRun\debug\0\com\google\android\gms\analyticsservices\app\library
>       at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\Jadayu\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRun\debug\0\com\google\android\gms\analyticsservices\app\library
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266)
>       at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
>       at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:58)
>       at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:53)
>       at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:53)
>       at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:53)
>       at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:53)
>       at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:53)
>       at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:53)
>       at com.android.utils.FileUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(FileUtils.java:238)
>       at com.android.utils.FileUtils.deletePath(FileUtils.java:59)
>       at com.android.utils.FileUtils.deleteDirectoryContents(FileUtils.java:74)
>       at com.android.utils.FileUtils.cleanOutputDir(FileUtils.java:101)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.doTransform(InstantRunTransform.java:271)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunTransform.transform(InstantRunTransform.java:186)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
>       at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
>       at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>       ... 49 more

i got this **error** what can i do to fix this

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do with the code and also share the concerned code snippet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Perform a **Build -> Clean Build**
2. If no luck then try, **File -> Try invalidate Caches and Restart**

Answer (score 0):

Please use code tags and share some part about your code where the problem happens. There is some bug reports about your issue. See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738061/java-nio-file-directorynotemptyexception-when-deleting-lastsuccessful-laststable)

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryNotEmptyException` means that there are files contained, which cannot be deleted, either due to permissions or due to files having an exclusive lock, because they are open.

in order to get around that, close Android Studio and the delete directory `C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\Jadayu\app\build` manually.